# tmux autocomplete command

Tags: tmux, autocomplete

I use this key-bind to launch a ssh session in a split window

```
bind-key S command-prompt -p "ssh" "splitw 'ssh %1'"
```

how I can get autocomplete in tmux command?

example

```
ssh hos<tab>
ssh host
```